# mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'uname'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /all_pts.php on line 16

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, server

Although I successfully connected to `wamp server` facing the problem as above when uploaded the data and `php file` using `FTP` on a remote server.

I tried all *password/username combination*.

I used with this web hosting but in-vain. Please suggest something that may be obvious but not getting.

> mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'uname'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /all_pts.php on line 16

Comment: Check for username/password and if it's correct then check for database privilege for username.

Comment: Thanks Disha, How could i possibly check the privilege for the remote database that i access using web-browser after entering username and password.

Comment: You need to login cPanel and check privileges inside `MySQL Databases` link

Comment: The question asked previously may be same but answer doesn't reflect about the cPanel. Besides i did not use a query through C:.......MySQL....

Answer (score 0):

You need to create database and database user via control panel of your hosting account. Mostly `cPanel` is used for it. Then you need to put information of the database and database user into `all_pts.php`

See [How to create a MySQL database in cPanel](http://www.interspire.com/content/2006/04/04/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-in-cpanel/)

Comment: Thanks Hassan, but afraid to say that username i used to get acccess to remote database(FTP) is different that i use to get direct access in web-browser. But i will give a try.

Comment: @AaronWaghmare what you are using `cPanel` of any other?

Comment: Yeah, i am using other cPanel for the service

Comment: @AaronWaghmare I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah Hassan, i used cPanel for the service and created database from that only. Then directly copied credentials to Excel sheet along with links so i can use in all_pts.php, then replaced excel info in php file. End result is this. Thanks i will repeat the procedure so if any space or special character if added will be sorted. Will get back you soon. Thanks again

Comment: I got the access using same credentials to create the database in phpMyadmin. Not sure whats wrong.